# Can two colliding photons create a Higgs Boson?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, higgs

The LHC discovered the Higgs using the following decay mode:
$$ H^0 \rightarrow \gamma \gamma $$

This got me thinking: if we reverse this mode, will it be valid? In some annihilation/decay pairs, these will stay valid:

$$e^+e^- \rightarrow \gamma\gamma$$

$$\gamma\gamma \rightarrow e^+e^-$$

So if the Higgs will decay into two high energy photons, will the annihilation of two high energy photons create a Higgs by this mode?:

$$ \gamma \gamma \rightarrow H^0 $$

Comment: I want to add a follow up question:  if there is scattering between photons via higs does this have any interesting or observable effects in a photon gas?

Comment: The fusion of a top quark-anti top quark pair can produce a Higgs boson, and they, in turn, are the byproducts of gluons. If you could produce such a pair with photons, then this would be feasible. Not likely, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In principle, yes. You can reverse *any* decay process and the corresponding synthesis will be valid - in this case, since $H_0\to\gamma\gamma$ happens, then $\gamma\gamma\to H_0$ will also happen, assuming the kinematics work out.

However, the corresponding probability is *very* small. Out of all the possible things that could happen when two photons cross paths, turning into a Higgs boson is a relatively unlikely one. In fact, by far the most common option is *nothing*, because photons don't directly interact with each other. In order to get an interaction, you need one of the photons to quantum-fluctuate into a pair of charged particles, so that the other photon can interact with one of them - this makes it a second-order interaction at best. And Higgs production is even more unlikely because photons don't interact with the Higgs either, so you need *another* fluctuation to go from the charged particles to the Higgs boson. All [the Feynman diagrams](http://inspirehep.net/record/929477/plots?ln=en) are third-order or higher, which makes for a very unlikely process indeed.

Comment: Are the cross-sections any larger in a strong (relevant) field?  For instance vacuum pairs near an event horizon and charged pairs near a charged particle?  If nonzero, how large can this be?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not sure offhand, though in a strong field there are a lot more photons to interact with so the overall Higgs production rate should rise.

Comment: I'll just add that for the same reasons of the coupling being indirect the two-photon decay channel for the Higgs is quite rare: it only represents 0.2% of all decays. This was a major challenge in trying to see the Higgs in this way, although the 'clarity' of the signal relative to jets of hadrons made it worth the trouble.